# How can I add the outcome of a function to a list in python?

Tags: python, list, primes

```
def b():
    a = int(input("Look up to: ")) // set the range to scan for primes
    for num in range(0, a):
        if prime(num) == True:
            print(num)
            print("adding to list")
            return num
            list = [num]
            list.append(num)

        else:
            print(num, "is not a prime")
```

So how can I append the outcome to "list" for each new prime?

Forgot to mention the function to check if num is prime:

```
def prime(num):
         for j in range (2, num):
               if (num % j) == 0 :
                    return False
         return True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few points:

- Once you `return` is executed, the value it is applied to is returned to whoever called the function and the code after return never executes.
- You're [shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the built-in function [`list()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) which returns a new list by calling a local variable `list`.
- The list is constantly **reconstructed** by calling `[num]` which is a shorthand for creating a **new** list containing only `num`. What you want to do is **update** it using [`append`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

Fixing the code, it may look something like:

```
def get_primes():
    a = int(input("Look up to: "))

    # 'primes' is a more suitable name for a list of primes
    # we're only creating the list *once*, and we're not shadowing 'list'
    primes = list()

    for candidate in range(0, a):
        if prime(candidate) == True:
            print(candidate)
            print("adding to list")
            primes.append(candidate)

        else:
            print(num, "is not a prime")

    # use return to return a result
    return primes
```

You can test this by calling `get_primes()`.

**Tip:** you could use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) to do the same thing `get_primes` does:

```
a = int(input("Look up to: "))
print(filter(prime, range(0, a)))
```

---

A minor note about the difference between `list` and `[]` is that you can change `list`'s behaviour, which gives finer control, while `[]`'s generated code calls `BUILD_LIST` directly (harder to change):

```
>>> dis.dis(lambda: [])
  1           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              3 RETURN_VALUE        

>>> dis.dis(lambda: list())
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (list)
              3 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

It really does not matter in this case, but @Thrustmaster suggested using `[]` in the comments since it some may see it as cleaner.

Comment: Allternative: `primes = []` will do just fine.

Comment: I wanted `list` to be included in the code because of the second point :)

Comment: Yes, I understand that. The comment was more for the OP than you. `primes = list()` sort of hurts my eyes.

Comment: thank you Reut!!!
Thinking of using dictionary, I suppose the same applies, right?
After all primes are unique.
thanks again!

Comment: @DimitriosKokkotis You could use a set: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets

Comment: You forgot to actually add to the list.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, lot of minor syntax errors. Let me `list` them down..

1. Python comments do not start with `//`, but with `#`. Ref. code line no: 2
2. list is a keyword in python, you should not use that in your variable declaration. Line ref: 8.
3. After you do a return, the code after that line will not be executed. Line Ref: 7.
4. You should not initialize list inside the `for` loop. It is getting initialized in every iteration.
5. Instead of `if prim(num) == True:`, you can simply write `if prim(num):`.

That said, the correct code should look as follows:

```
def b():
    a = int(input("Look up to: ")) # set the range to scan for primes
    primes = [] #Your list
    for num in range(0, a):
        if prime(num):
            print(num)
            print("adding to list")
            primes.append(num)

        else:
            print(num, "is not a prime")

    return primes
```

Hope it helps .. :)

Comment: While I appreciate the `list` pun and the fact that your numbered points are _solid_, the correct code does not look correct at all... Where is the function indentation and why is the return statement inside the for loop?

Comment: indentation was a copy-paste mistake, and return was mine.. note to self: never answer while half asleep.. editing now..

Comment: Now there is _no_ `return` statement in the function, which now returns `None`.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. The strange thing about your code is where you've placed the `return` statement. Try this:

```
def b():
    primesList = []
    a = int(input("Look up to: "))
    for num in range(0, a):
        if prime(num) == True:
            print(num)
            print("adding to list")
            primesList.append(num)

        else:
            print(num, "is not a prime")

     return primesList
```

Notice that your original return statement would have ended your function *early*, in fact even before your list would have had the chance to append *any prime number at all*. The other important point here is that you should never shadow a built-in type (`list` in this case), or other built-in functions (like `map`, `sorted`, etc.).

It's also enough to simply initialize the `primesList` once and append the `num` integers inside the `for loop`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks to be a mix of C and Python (don't use // as comments).
I assume your program is looking for prime numbers up to n. Here is how one might go about implementing this:

```
import math
def is_prime(n):
    if n % 2 == 0 and n > 2: 
        return False
    for i in range(3, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1, 2):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

def find_primes(a, b):
    primes = []
    for i in range(a, b):
        if is_prime(i):
            primes.append(i)
    return primes
```

Comment: thank you Billylegota, but I am not so advanced, cant figure out what is doing. It seems to run faster though :S, hope you are not messing with my PC :P

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are good and address the main issue that you had with rebinding your list variable and failing to return the primes list from function `b()`.

I think it's worth mentioning that a list comprehension can be used to succinctly code the prime list generation:

```
def prime(num):
         for j in range (2, num):
               if (num % j) == 0 :
                    return False
         return True

def get_primes(low, high):
    return [n for n in range(low, high+1) if prime(n)]

>>> a = input("Look up to: ")
11
>>> get_primes(0, a)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11]
>>> get_primes(5, a)
[5, 7, 11]
```

Notes:

1. Passing the "up to" value into the function is more flexible than
   prompting for it in the function.
2. "Up to" should be inclusive, e.g. get_primes(0, 11) should include 11 in the result. Therefore you need to add one to the upper value when calling `range()`.
3. Passing `low` and `high` allows you to generate primes for arbitrary ranges.
4. You can wrap the list comprehension with `set()` to have the result returned as a set.